# Shell Scripting. How to copy one file to all the folders in PWD

Tags: bash, shell, unix

sorry i am new to shell scripting

I have few folders in PWD. i need to copy one file to all the folders in PWD. FIle is also stored in present working directory . How can i do that?

Comment: writing code would be a good start...

Comment: i will edit the question with what i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
for d in */; do cp -v ./file "$d/"; done
```